# Spring form error messages property file rules?

Tags: spring-mvc, validation

What are the rules for an error messages property file? Is there a specification somewhere?

For example, I have several form fields, and I want a single message defined in my properties file that will apply to all of the fields . Instead of having to do this:

```
FormController.name[not.blank] = This field is required.
FormController.address[not.blank] = This field is required.
FormController.city[not.blank] = This field is required.
....
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
FormController.*[not.blank] = This field is required.
```

Or this:

```
*[not.blank] = This field is required.
```

But I have no clue about the rules of the properties file (btw those ways don't work). Where are the rules defined?

**EDIT:**
After reading the links suggested by skaffman, I'm still having problems. The javadoc for DefaultMessageCodesResolver says:

> Will create two message codes for an
>   object error, in the following order:
>
> 1.: code + "." + object name,
>   2.: code

But when I list the error codes for my ObjectError (my command object is called newAccountRequest), it doesn't include either of those error codes:

> codes [NewAccountRequest.firstName[not.blank].newAccountRequest.firstName,NewAccountRequest.firstName[not.blank].firstName,NewAccountRequest.firstName[not.blank].java.lang.String,NewAccountRequest.firstName[not.blank]]

In fact, it doesn't include any error codes that I could generically access with something like:

> not.blank.newAccountRequest

So, I'm back where I started =(

Answer (score 1):

The rules for message keys are summarised [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion), and described in detail [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html).